# Regex - Match the last 5 characters at the end of file

Tags: regex, character, notepad++

I need solution to match the last 5 characters of text file.

I try this, but is not working.

> .{5}\z

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Works well for me, try to upgrade npp. Eventually change the dot for `[\s\S]` if the last five characters contain a newline.

Comment: With an uppercase `\Z`: https://regex101.com/r/hvihRF/1

Comment: Works with `\Z` for me - works with `\z` if there are actually 5 chars in the last line, no trailing newlines,

Comment: @SebastianProske: 7.1 I win.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution:**

FIND:  `[\s\S]{5}\z`

Answer (score 2):

I cannot reproduce this with Notepad++ V7.1. However note, that `.{5}\z` will only match, if there are actually 5 characters in the last line, e.g. a trailing newline will force it to not match. Also make sure, that you have checked *regular expression* in the search dialog.

If there are trainling newlines, you might want to use `\Z` instead of `\z`.
If there might be less than 5 characters, you could use `.{0,5}` instead or check *. matches newline* to match over multiple lines.